# Cannot access cdn.redhat.com from my Linux VM. please find the attached screenshot and provide me the solution

Tags: linux, redhat

## [root@localhost ~]# yum install ksh
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 22:24:52 ago on Tue 25 May 2021 01:12:00 AM EDT.
Dependencies resolved.

## Package                           Architecture                         Version                                         Repository                                                      Size

Installing:
ksh                               x86_64                               20120801-254.el8                                rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms                               926 k

## Transaction Summary

Install  1 Package

Total download size: 926 k
Installed size: 3.2 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
[MIRROR] ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel8/8/x86_64/appstream/os/Packages/k/ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm [Failed to connect to cdn.redhat.com port 443: No route to host]
[MIRROR] ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel8/8/x86_64/appstream/os/Packages/k/ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm [Failed to connect to cdn.redhat.com port 443: No route to host]
[MIRROR] ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel8/8/x86_64/appstream/os/Packages/k/ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm [Failed to connect to cdn.redhat.com port 443: No route to host]
[MIRROR] ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm: Curl error (7): Couldn't connect to server for https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel8/8/x86_64/appstream/os/Packages/k/ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm [Failed to connect to cdn.redhat.com port 443: No route to host]
[FAILED] ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm: No more mirrors to try - All mirrors were already tried without success

The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: Error downloading packages:
Cannot download Packages/k/ksh-20120801-254.el8.x86_64.rpm: All mirrors were tried

Comment: You don't have Internet connectivity.  Can you do `ping 4.2.2.2`?

Comment: No I cannot ping it. but i can ping google.com

Comment: Do you have an extra-restrictive firewall on your PC or on your network?  Can you `ping cdn.redhat.com`?  How have you configured the network on your VM?

Comment: I am not able to ping cdn.redhat.com , I am  not able to connect to internet on my VM.

Comment: i have selected bridge adapter for my network

Comment: Then you have a networking issue.  You need to chase that down.  You may need to ask the RedHat community.